# How to show the following inequality in 3 variables

Tags: inequality

Prove
$$\left(1-\frac{xz}{y}\right)^{y+1}\geq \left(\left(1-z\right)\left(1-\frac{z}{y}\right)\right)^{x}$$
for all $x,y,z$ such that $2 \leq x+1 \leq y$, $0\leq z \leq 1$, $y \geq 2$.

Comment: From where you got this? I am asking because sometimes knowing the source can help us to solve the problem.

Comment: Visual, what did you try?

Comment: actually i tried for quite sometime and i couldn't, but now after posting it i solved it. it can be done by taking log of both sides and comparing the nth term of the expansion of both sides.